# Eternicode datepicker start date today

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

First time using [etrnicode bootstrap datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/) and i cannot set tthe start date to today and disable selection of previous dates.

My code is:

```
$('#issue_date').datepicker({
    startDate: '+0d'
}).on('changeDate', function(){
   ... stuff happens here
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('#issue_date').datepicker({
    startDate: new date()
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    ... stuff happens here
});
```

But I can still select yesterday. What have I missed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can see in your second attempt is that `date()` must be capitalized.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hous9y5L/298/).

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: new Date()
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    console.log("Hello");
});
```